# Boost converter

Tags: boost, converter

I'm trying to build a 12v to 48v boost converter. I have an output current requirement of 5A. The efficiency most moor than 90%. which component can I used?

Comment: Buy a premade module.

Answer (score 6):

Seriously, this is well over your head if you have to ask here, especially if you think the only issue is "which component can I used?".

48 V at 5 A is 240 W.  That is not a trivial amount of power.  90% efficient for a boost converter is not impossible, but you really have to know what you're doing and be aware of all the little tricks to not lose a percent or two here or there.  This is simply not a beginner project.

With 240 W out and 90% efficiency, 267 W will have to go in with 27 W getting dissipated as heat.  Are you prepared for that much heat?  Note also that the input will be over 22 A at 12 V.

Even if you do manage to pull this off somehow, you will have spent many many hours doing it.  Clearly this is not a commercial product, since then there'd be a senior engineer you'd be working under.

Go buy something off the shelf.